# Anaconda cannot open a terminal in kde linux

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, anaconda

Running Kubuntu 18.04.  Anaconda installs as per usual, and works in all ways except that it cannot open a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that anaconda doesn't work with konsole.  It works with the gnome-terminal-server (/usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server).  So you have to install the "gnome-terminal" package and start gnome-terminal once to set it up.

ttfn
wcn